# How to set on touch listener for multiple image views?

Tags: java, android, imageview, ontouchlistener

I created an onTouchListener for my ImageView "car" and want to do the same for another ImageView, however I can't figure out how. So my question is:

How do you use one onTouchListener that detects the MotionEvents of two separate ImageViews and makes something happen accordingly?

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {

    //int action = event.getAction();
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                carcolor.setBackgroundColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));

                car.startAnimation(pressdown);
                pressdown.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                        carback.setScaleX((float) 0.9);
                        carback.setScaleY((float) 0.9);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                        carback.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        car.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                    }
                });

                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                car.startAnimation(release);

                carcolor.setBackgroundColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.unpressed));

                release.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                        carback.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                        car.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                    }
                });


                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                break;
        }
        return true;

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should implement the onTouchListener like:

```
        imageView.setOnTouchListener(this);
```

and init it like :

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    ImageView view = (ImageView) v;
    switch (view.getId()){
        case R.id.car1: // example id
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                    break;
            }
            break;
        case R.id.car2: // example id
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                    break;
            }
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your activity is implementing the onTouchListener event (I'm assuming based on the override), on your other ImageView just do the following

```
imageView.setOnTouchListener(this);
```

Where this is the current activity.

**EDIT:** Based on your comment

```
public class ImageView1Listener implements OnTouchListener
{
  **** OVERRIDES****
}

public class ImageView2Listener implements OnTouchListener{
**** OVERRIDS FOR THIS IMAGE****
}
```

then in your main remove the implements OnTouchListener and use bind it programatically

```
 imageView1.setOnClickListener(new ImageViewListener1());
 imageView2.setOnClickListener(new ImageViewListener2());
```

Comment: That only answers half of the question. How do you give both image views different functions and detect their motions separately

Comment: Ah that wasn't clear by your question - you can create a class the implements the OnTouchListener unique for each and take it off the class implementation

Comment: I updated it to reflect better what my last comment ment

Answer (score 1):

Attach the listener to the parent of them.
Than, use `gesturesDetector` as stated here:
https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector.html

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements 
        GestureDetector.OnGestureListener,
        GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener{

    private static final String DEBUG_TAG = "Gestures";
    private GestureDetectorCompat mDetector; 

    // Called when the activity is first created. 
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // Instantiate the gesture detector with the
        // application context and an implementation of
        // GestureDetector.OnGestureListener
        mDetector = new GestureDetectorCompat(this,this);
        // Set the gesture detector as the double tap
        // listener.
        mDetector.setOnDoubleTapListener(this);
    }

    @Override 
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){ 
        this.mDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        // Be sure to call the superclass implementation
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent event) {
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "onSingleTapConfirmed: " + event.toString());
        return true;
    }
    ....
}
```

Comment: @LincolnWhite , in this example I've only pasted the `onSingleTapConfirmed` event. Open the url. You can read more examples inside the link. Or if not, what do you need?